# How to reinit actions in redux-observable?

Tags: redux, observable, redux-observable

For example, this code [this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/mubufa/edit?js,output):

```
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PING)
    .delay(1000) // Asynchronously wait 1000ms then continue
    .mapTo({ type: PONG })
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(CANCEL));
```

When I use `takeUntil` as above, after dispatching the `CANCEL` action and a delay of 1 second, the action never fires again. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is a subtle but critical misunderstanding of how RxJS works--but fear not, this is very common.

So given your example:

```js
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PING)
    .delay(1000)
    .mapTo({ type: PONG })
    .takeUntil(action$.ofType(CANCEL));
```

This epic's behavior can be described as filtering out all actions that don't match type `PING`. When an action matches, wait 1000ms and then map that action to a different action `{ type: PONG }`, which will be emitted and then dispatched by redux-observable. If at **any** time while the app is running someone dispatches an action of type `CANCEL`, then **unsubscribe** from the source, which means this entire chain will unsubscribe, terminating the epic.

It might be helpful to see how this looks if you did it imperatively:

```js
const pingEpic = action$ => {
  return new Rx.Observable(observer => {
    console.log('[pingEpic] subscribe');
    let timer;

    const subscription = action$.subscribe(action => {
      console.log('[pingEpic] received action: ' + action.type);

      // When anyone dispatches CANCEL, we stop listening entirely!
      if (action.type === CANCEL) {
        observer.complete();
        return;
      }

      if (action.type === PING) {
        timer = setTimeout(() => {
          const output = { type: PONG };
          observer.next(output);
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    return {
      unsubscribe() {
        console.log('[pingEpic] unsubscribe');
        clearTimeout(timer);
        subscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    };
  });
};
```

You can run this code with a fake store here: http://jsbin.com/zeqasih/edit?js,console

---

Instead, what you usually want to do is insulate the subscriber chain you want to be cancellable from the top-level chain that is suppose to listen indefinitely. Although your example (amended from the docs) is contrived, let's run through it first.

Here we use the [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) operator to let us take the matched action and map to **another, separate observable chain**.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/nofato/edit?js,output

```js
const pingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(PING)
    .mergeMap(() =>
      Observable.timer(1000)
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(CANCEL))
        .mapTo({ type: PONG })
    );
```

We use [`Observable.timer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#static-method-timer) to wait 1000ms, then map the value it emits (which happens be to be the number zero, but that's not important here) to our `PONG` action. We also say we want to "take" from the timer source until either it completes normally or we receive an action of type `CANCEL`.

This isolates the chains because `mergeMap` will continue to subscribe to the observable you return until it errors or completes. But when that happens, it doesn't *itself* stop subscribing to the source you applied it to; the `action$.ofType(PING)` in this example.

A more real-world example is in the redux-observable docs in the [Cancellation section](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html)

> Here we placed the .takeUntil() after inside our .mergeMap(), but after our AJAX call; this is important because we want to cancel only the AJAX request, not stop the Epic from listening for any future actions.

```js
const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(fetchUserFulfilled)
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED))
    );
```

This all may sound confusing, but like most powerful things, once you get it, it'll become intuitive. Ben Lesh does an excellent job of explaining how Observables work in [his recent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE), including discussing how operators are a chain of Observables and even about isolating subscriber chains. Even though the talk is at AngularConnect, it's not Angular specific.

---

As an aside, it's important to note that your epics do not swallow or otherwise prevent actions from reaching the reducers, e.g. when you map an incoming action to another, different action. In fact, when your epic receives an action, it has *already been through your reducers*. Think of your epics as sidecar processes that listens to a stream of your apps actions, but can't prevent normal redux things from happening, it can only emit new actions.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.